# Nativescript RadSideDrawer routing issue

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-routing

Attempting to use NativeScript RadSideDrawer with angular using this example:
https://gist.github.com/NathanWalker/e8f4f7c42af04fc725764a9867936e3d

The following routing error occurs when I navigate to the route /home/feed:

```
JS: Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'FeedComponent' ; Zone: <root> ; 
Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'FeedComponent' Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'FeedComponent'
```

The routes that don't use the side-drawer (IE don't have the 'home' parent) work fine.

app.component.ts (root component)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ppc-app',
  template: '<StackLayout><page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet></StackLayout>',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

app.routes.ts

```
export const routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'feed', component: FeedComponent }  <-- this route fails
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', children: [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },  <-- these routes work
    { path: 'type', component: ChooseTypeComponent }  <-- these routes work
  ]}
];
```

home.component.ts

```
<ActionBar title="Plant Powered Community">
  <ActionItem (tap)="toggle()">
    <!-- example: using font-awesome for hamburger menu but you can use whatever you'd like -->
    <Button class="fa" text="&#xf0c9;"></Button> 
    <!-- however in your project, would be easier to use this plugin: https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fonticon -->
  </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<RadSideDrawer #drawer [transition]="sideDrawerTransition" selectionBehavior="None">
  <StackLayout tkDrawerContent>
    <!-- anything you want in drawer -->
    <!-- for example: -->
    <!-- you want options {exact: true} on the first one because otherwise it would be considered active when 'Other Page' in active as well -->
    <Button text="Home" [nsRouterLink]="['/home']" nsRouterLinkActive="active" [nsRouterLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"></Button>
    <Button text="Other Page" [nsRouterLink]="['/home/otherPath']" nsRouterLinkActive="active"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Comment: Not sure why you added the `StackLayout` around the `page-router-outlet` in the app.component HTML. It should not be required and could actually break things.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is the structure in the file app.routes.ts

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home/feed',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
            {path: 'type', component: ChooseTypeComponent },
            {path: 'feed', component: FeedComponent }
        ]
},
```

];

I have created a simple RadSideDrawer example, see if it helps.

https://github.com/simonettoa/nativescript-RadSideDrawer